# Substitute Milk for Water in Bread

Tags: baking

I want to substitute milk for the water called for in my recipe for bread. The recipe calls for 3 cups water. Home much milk should I use?

Comment: could you switch for a bread recipe that has milk as one of its ingredient ?à

Comment: Milk has different properties to water, so substituting in milk could cause an undesired outcome. It is better to follow *[Max](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/substitute-milk-for-water-in-bread#comment168774_105337)'s* suggestion.

Comment: If you have cooked a recipe for a while you might be up for experimentation this time. Milk is often used in bread and so the option seems reasonable. We can’t really say how much you should use without knowing the ratios. If you are putting heaps of milk in your bread be aware that the extra sugars may mean the loaf browns more quickly than the same recipe made only with water.